# boost::iostreams decompression returns an empty stream

Tags: c++, boost, compression, gzip, iostream

I have a seemingly basic issue that I've been tackling for the past couple of days and can't seem to find an answer for. I have read multiple answers for similar issues, but none seems to work for me.

I have been simply trying to use boost's compression / decompression functions, but I figure I must be using it incorrectly. My goal is quite simple - create a string, compress it and write to file, read the compressed file, decompress it and print to std::cout (or any other stream for that matter).
I used the following code:

```
// write files
std::stringstream str;
str << "SampleString";

std::ofstream outFile_raw("rawFile");
std::ofstream outFile_comp("compressedFile);

boost::iostreams::filtering_istream filteredString;
filteredString.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor());
filteredString.push(str);

boost::iostreams::copy(str, outFile_raw);
boost::iostreams::copy(filteredString, outFile_comp);

\\read files
std::ifstream inFile_raw("rawFile");
std::ifstream inFile_comp("compressedFile);

boost::iostreams::filtering_istream filteredInput;
filteredInput.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
filteredInput.push(inFile_comp);

boost::iostreams::copy(inFile_raw, std::cout);
boost::iostreams::copy(filteredInput, std::cout);
```

The writing phase works as it should - two files are created, one with an expected size (stringLength bytes), and a smaller one.
Upon reading, for some reason only the raw file is read successfully, while the compressed one prints nothing.

I have tried several methods in order to debug this issue:

- Getting the stream length with seekg and tellg, in order to verify that the stream is indeed empty
- using stream << filteredStream.rdbuf(); instead of boost::iostreams::copy
- Using filtering_istreambuf insteaf of filtering_istream (what is the difference? When should I use each one?)
- Using other compression algorithms, such as gzip and bzip2.
- Adding inFile_comp.close();  before and after pushing it to the filtering stream (One approach does not help, the other yields an iostream stream error exception.

I feel like there is a basic concept I am missing, can anyone please help me figure it out?

EDIT: After further investigating the issue, I have come to an interesting situation- During zlib and gzip compression, the entire process is completed successfully for a small file (~5KB, which is compressed to ~200 bytes), yet an "iostream stream error" exception is thrown for a larger file (~55MB, compressed to ~320KB).

For bzip2 compression, the exception is thrown in both cases. Could it have something to do with the decompressor buffer size?
I am getting pretty hopeless at this stage..

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `str` twice. After using it the first time it is at end-of-stream, so nothing will be read the second time.

Besides this, either explicitly flush your streams and buffers, or limit the scope of the objects so it happens automatically:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0dc4e1ab8ddf1bb1)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    // write files
    {
        std::stringstream str("SampleString");
        std::ofstream outFile_raw("rawFile");
        boost::iostreams::copy(str, outFile_raw);
    }
    {
        std::stringstream str("SampleString");
        std::ofstream outFile_comp("compressedFile");

        boost::iostreams::filtering_istream filteredString;
        filteredString.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor());
        filteredString.push(str);

        boost::iostreams::copy(filteredString, outFile_comp);

        outFile_comp.flush();
        outFile_comp.close();
    }

    //read files
    {
        std::ifstream inFile_raw("rawFile");
        boost::iostreams::copy(inFile_raw, std::cout << "\n inFile_raw: ");
    }
    {
        std::ifstream inFile_comp("compressedFile");

        boost::iostreams::filtering_istream filteredInput;
        filteredInput.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
        filteredInput.push(inFile_comp);

        boost::iostreams::copy(filteredInput, std::cout << "\n filteredInput: ");
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
 inFile_raw: SampleString
 filteredInput: SampleString
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift response! I managed to get it to decompress correctly, however I encounter something strange - I am trying to read two compressed files (separately), both of them compressed and created in the same as the above code. While the first, smaller one decompresses successfully, the second, larger one (55MB uncompressed, 320KB compressed) throws an "input stream error" exception (I tried catching the exception but it does not provide any further information). Do you have any insight as to why it would work for one file but not the other?

Comment: Not really. If you can't solve it, please post a new question with a SSCCE (preferrably with a link to a document that fails on your system)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Q&A are transactions here. Drawing it out and asking follow-up questions makes the question off-topic (others will never have "precisely the same question" and can't find answers buried in comments)